# Objective-C: initWithName:(char *)string

Tags: objective-c

How would you read this in English? My concern is with the pointer. Is that pointer associated with char or with string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

it's a *pointer to char* parameter named **string**.

So:

- `char *` is the type of the parameter following it
- `string` is the name of the parameter (and you should refer to this one in method body)

Answer (score 0):

The part in parentheses describes the type of the parameter immediately following it—in this case, a pointer to some `char`s.

Comment: Thanks everybody, you guys are great. Believe it or not I have been coding with Objective-C for awhile now. It's snippets of code & syntax like this that sometimes confuse the hell out of me. I finally had to brave up and ask the question. And I'm coming from a C background which i haven't touched in 16 years.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is a C string, which is also named *string*.

```
[obj initWithName: "whatever"];
```

C strings are a `'\0'` terminated sequence of chars, and are declared as `char *`.

```
char *foo = "a C string";
NSString *bar = @"an objc string";
```

Answer (score 0):

*string* is just the name of the parameter.

The type of the parameter is a pointer to a `char`.